# Java HTTP Request for PHP

Tags: java, php, http

So i am trying to send some variables to my localhost which runs a php file which should output the variable.

```
URL url = null;
try {
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    String MontagMittagVorspeise = "value1";
    String query = String.format("param1=%s", URLEncoder.encode(MontagMittagVorspeise, charset));
    url = new URL("127.0.0.1/Haunsbot/Hauns.php");
    URLConnection connection = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And this is my PHP:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET["MontagMittagVorspeise"]))
{echo "Vehicle :".$_GET["MontagMittagVorspeise"];}
?>
```

And IntelliJ gives me the following error: `java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: 127.0.0.1/Haunsbot/Hauns.php`

Can someone help me?:)

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/Haunsbot/Hauns.php <- this is the correct url, you have to put http:// before the host ip address

Comment: code may have other errors as well, but start with `new URL("http://...")`

Comment: `param1` != `MontagMittagVorspeise`

Comment: Your query parameter name is LITERALLY `param1`. If you'd done ANY kind of basic debugging, like `var_dump($_GET)`, you'd have seen this.

Comment: thanks guys, thats all actually very obvious all of that xD im just super new to java and PHP so its not that easy for me! Also trying intelliJ and not VS (i normally code in C#) and thats all so much new things to learn right now :)